# Alterar valor de sequence com subselect

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com o seguinte caso: Preciso alterar o valor de umas sequences de acordo com o max(id) da tabela referente, estou tentando fazer algo do tipo:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE CFOP_SEQ INCREMENT BY (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM CFOP);
```

Porém me retorna a mensagem "Número inválido". Alguém sabe como posso resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar uma pl para fazer isso. Armazenando o valor do select dentro de uma variável utilizando o **into** e depois executando o *alter* com o **execute immediate**.

```
declare
  maxId number;
begin 

  SELECT MAX(ID)+1 
    into maxId
  FROM CFOP;

  execute immediate 'ALTER SEQUENCE CFOP_SEQ INCREMENT BY '||maxId;
end;
/
```

Caso você precise escrever qualquer outro comando pode adicionar ele
direto no corpo da PL/SQL, nos casos de **SELECT** você precisa adicionar os retornos em variáveis ou em um curso utilizando o **INTO**.

Você só utiliza o execute immedia
Segue o link para melhor informações sobre PL/SQL.

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado. Uma dúvida como eu faço pra executar mais 2 comandos em sequência ?

Comment: são alters também ?

Comment: Alter e um select.

Comment: Sim, na verdade em uma PL você consegue praticamente tudo.

Comment: Pode editar a resposta dando um exemplo?